# Horizontal scroll with mouse wheel at Visual Studio Preview 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

So I found this extension for Visual Studio Preview 2019 to scroll horizontally with the mouse wheel when holding the shift key called: SideScroller.
But I can't find the same extension for Visual Studio Preview 2022. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Update:](https://github.com/drewnoakes/vs-side-scroller/issues/6#issuecomment-946351247)

> "Version 1.2 is now available in the marketplace, with support for
> VS2022. Please test it out let me know if you see any issues. Thanks
> everyone for your patience!"

If you look up the extension in the [VS Extension Gallery](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=drewnoakes.SideScroller), you'll find that has [a GitHub project](https://github.com/drewnoakes/vs-side-scroller).  From there, you could try to fix it up to install on VS2022 (and maybe even send a pull request), or you might look at this [issue](https://github.com/drewnoakes/vs-side-scroller/issues/6) asking for VS2022 support, with a workaround/hack in the comments.